# Why table is not created in SQLite Android studio 3.1.4 or 3.2.1

Tags: android-sqlite

Why table is not created in SQLite Android studio 3.1.4 or 3.2.1
I use this code at home on Android studio 3.1 works perfectly but in 3.1.4 and 3.2.1 which I use at school it make the database but not the table.

I have used logcat to print the query and paste it into db browser and it works perfectly and creates the table. I have done a number of Log.d in the onCreate() method to confirm the code is arriving in that method and it is arriving in the method.

```
public class SQLCon extends SQLiteOpenHelper
 {
    public static final String DBNAME = "unidb.db";
    public static int VER = 1;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    final String CREATEUSERTABLE = "CREATE Table IF NOT EXISTS "+
            ContractSQL.User.TABLE_NAME+"( "+
            ContractSQL.User.ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY autoincrement,"+
            ContractSQL.User.FN+" varchar(45),"+
            ContractSQL.User.SN+" varchar(45),"+
            ContractSQL.User.EM+" varchar(45),"+
            ContractSQL.User.GROUP+" varchar(45),"+
            ContractSQL.User.PW+ " varchar(45));";

    public SQLCon(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, VER);

 this.getWritableDatabase();
        //onCreate(this.getWritableDatabase());
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        Log.d("CREATEUSERTABLETAG", CREATEUSERTABLE);

        db.execSQL(CREATEUSERTABLE);
        //this.getWritableDatabase().execSQL(CREATEUSERTABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

}


Contract Class:



 public final class ContractSQL
 {
    private ContractSQL(){}

    public static class User
    {
        public static final String TABLE_NAME = "_user_";
        public static final String ID = "_id_";
        public static final String FN = "_fn_";
        public static final String SN = "_sn_";
        public static final String GROUP = "_group_";
        public static final String PW = "_pw_";
        public static final String EM = "_em_";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Copying the above code into SQLCon.java and ContractSQL.java respectively and then utilising the code from an activity using :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    AdminSQLiteOpenHelper mASQLiteHlpr;
    SQLCon mSQLcon;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mSQLcon = new SQLCon(this);
        Cursor csr = mSQLcon.getWritableDatabase().query("sqlite_master",null,null,null,null,null,null);
        while (csr.moveToNext()) {
            Log.d("DBINFO", "Found Item " + csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex("name")));
        }
        csr.close();
    }
}
```

Works fine and produces the following in the log :-

```
10-25 19:40:37.311 1164-1164/axtest.axtest D/CREATEUSERTABLETAG: CREATE Table IF NOT EXISTS _user_( _id_ INTEGER PRIMARY KEY autoincrement,_fn_ varchar(45),_sn_ varchar(45),_em_ varchar(45),_group_ varchar(45),_pw_ varchar(45));
10-25 19:40:37.311 1164-1164/axtest.axtest D/DBINFO: Found Item android_metadata
10-25 19:40:37.311 1164-1164/axtest.axtest D/DBINFO: Found Item _user_
10-25 19:40:37.311 1164-1164/axtest.axtest D/DBINFO: Found Item sqlite_sequence
```

- android_metadata being a table created by the SQLite code available with android (it is used for the locale).
- sqlite_sequence is created because you have coded AUTOINCREMENT. It contains the highest **rowid** used to date (unless modified).

  - coding `?? INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` (with or without AUTOINCREMENT)makes the column ?? (*id* in your case) an alias of the special column **rowid**. **rowid** is a unqiue signed 64 bit integer. It will initially be 1 and will then generally increment by 1 (although there is no guarantee that it will).
  - AUTOINCREMENT has overheads and only introduces a constraint that the **rowid** must always be larger. It is rarely required and it is recommended to not use AUTOINCREMENT.[SQLite Autoincrement](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html)

As such, it would appear that you are either not checking that the table exists using a sound method (an example of a sound method is included in the code above) or that there are some external constraints due to the different environments.

**Adopting the above code that queries the *`sqlite_master`* table, would show if the table is being created.**